# QVariantMap Json Parsing in QT

Tags: qt, qt4, qjson

I am using the following code for parsing:

```
QJson::Parser parser;
bool ok;
QVariantMap result=parser.parse (cityReply->readAll(),&ok).toMap();
if (!ok)
{
    qFatal("An error occurred during parsing");
    exit (1);
}

foreach (QVariant city, result.toList())
{
    QVariantMap names = city.toMap();
    qDebug() << "\t-" << names["name"].toString();
}
```

My json String is `[{"id":2,"name":"AAA"},{"id":1,"name":"BBB"}]`.

I got the following error:

> 'class QVariantMap' has no member named 'toList'.

is it possible to convert the QMap to QList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result` contain a serialized array as `QVariant`. You need to extract it before calling the `toList()` function. Since array is not named in Json string, you can access it by getting the first `QVariant` in the map and the doing what you have written in the question.

Comment: sorry.. could you please explain little bit more.

Comment: Regarding the Json string, the QVariantMap only contains one element: the array. Just get it using the QMap function and then convert it to a list

Comment: @PatriceBernassola Can you please post a code sample using QMap to extract from the array as suggested in the answer? I am new to this api and have a similar problem. My code resembles the above with the exception that my json contains an array name too i.e.         [{"chan":{"id":1, "name":"one"}},{"chan":{"id":2,"name":"two"}}]

Comment: QJson official documentation provide code example for each type of serialized data: http://qjson.sourceforge.net/usage/. Check how plugins array is deserialized.